# About double (iterated) complex series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{ c_{kn}\}$ be a double sequence of complex numbers such that  $$\sum_{k=n}^\infty c_{kn}=C_n$$ for all positive integers $n$.

Is it true that 
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=n}^N c_{kn}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n \;\;?
$$
(and so,  if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ is also convergent, then 
$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=n}^N c_{kn}=\sum_{n=1}^
\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty c_{kn}
$ is convergent?)

If no, What conditions does it need to be kept in?

Comment: In the first definition - are all series convergent?

Comment: Any reasonable statement is true if the series involved converge absolutely. Otherwise, they are probably wrong.

Comment: The precise "absolute convergence" condition here is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k-n}^\infty |c_{kn}| < +\infty.$$  As Alex said, your conclusion will hold then.

Answer (score 3):

I think here is a counterexample: $c_{n,n}=n$, $c_{n+1,n}=-n$, $c_{kn}=0$ otherwise. Then everything converges ($C_n=0$ for all $n$), but the double sum in the question equals $N$.

The standard condition would be absolute convergence of the double series: all partial sums of $|c_{kn}|$ should be bounded.

Changing $n$ to a given sequence $a_n$ in the def, you'll have the double sum equal to $a_N$, which would converge to any prescribed number (whereas $\sum C_n$ is still $0$).

Comment: Wouldn't the double sum be  $N(N+1)/2$?

Comment: No, I think not. The rest just cancels. In fact, changing $n$ to a given sequence $a_n$ in the def, you'll have the double sum equal to $a_N$, which would converge to any prescribed number (whereas $\sum C_n$ is still $0$).

Comment: you are right, my mistake (i forgot to cancel the previous subsums).

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is another counterexample.  Using Maple for the computations...
$$
c_{kn}=\frac{(-1)^k}{k}
$$
then
$$
C_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{2}\left(\Psi\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)
-\Psi\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\right)
$$
where $\Psi$ is the digamma function, $\Psi(x) = \Gamma'(x)/\Gamma(x)$.  Now
$$
C_n =\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right),
$$
so the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n$ converges (conditionally).

> In fact, numerically we have
>   $$
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n = -0.50000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
> $$
>   so I assume the sum is exactly $-1/2$.

On the other hand, what about the limit of
$$
U_N:=\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=n}^N c_{kn}
$$
In fact,
$$
U_N - U_{N-1} = \sum_{n=1}^N c_{Nn} = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^N}{N} = (-1)^N
$$
so this does not converge.